# How to display/Hide a div based on a radio button selection in angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, angular6

My HTML file,

```
  <input type="radio" id="com" name="communication" value="full" (click)= "function(1)">
   <input type="radio" id="com2" name="communication" value="half" (click)= "function(2)">
   <input type="radio" id="com3" name="communication" value="oth" (click)= "function(3)">

  <div id="Flag1" [disabled]="Flag1" [(ngModel)]="Flag1" ngDefaultControl>

  some content....A
  </div>
  <div id="Flag2" [disabled]="Flag2" [(ngModel)]="Flag2" ngDefaultControl>

  some content....B
  </div>
  <div id="Flag3" [disabled]="Flag3" [(ngModel)]="Flag3" ngDefaultControl>

  some content....C
  </div>
```

My ts file:

```
Flag1=false;
Flag2=false; 
Flag3=false; 
function(x) {
if(x==1){
    alert("inside 1");
  this.Flag1=false;
  this.Flag2=false;
  this.Flag3=false;
}
else if(x==2){
    alert("inside 2");
  this.Flag1=false;
  this.Flag2=false;
  this.Flag3=false;

}
else if(x==3){
    alert("inside 3");
  this.Flag1=true;
  this.Flag2=true;
  this.Flag3=true;
 }
}
```

If i click on first & second radio btn, I need to hide all other div. If I click on third btn I need to display all the div. But this doesnt seems to affect my html page. Can anybody tell me how to do this in angular 6?

Comment: use `*ngIf` directive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `*ngIf`

```
<div *ngIf="Flag1" id="Flag1" [disabled]="Flag1" [(ngModel)]="Flag1" ngDefaultControl>

  some content....A
</div>
```

Also, remove `disabled`, & `ngModel`, that's not useful I guess.

Comment: Yes sure. I have approved.